# Spring WS wsdl to java

Tags: cxf, axis, spring-ws, wsdl2java

I'm looking to use some framework to help generate java client bindings based on wsdl's provided by the service provider.

There are options like Axis and CXF but I'm also looking at Spring-WS.

Although Spring-WS has great support to author the web service in the first place, it doesn't seem to have client side capabilities like wsdl to java generation (unless I am missing something).

Does that mean that Spring WS is not a good option for me?

Comment: Q: I don't understand why you can't auto-generate Java (e.g. using an Axis2 or CXF based GUI tool that's integrated with your IDE), then just fill in the implementation however you like?  Including an implementation that uses Spring/Hibernate, if you so choose?

Comment: I can absolutely do that. My question is weather or not i can do the same using Spring WS. I already use Spring WS as a web service provider and it would be nice to use the same tool as a web service client as well. If that's not an option, I'll fall back on CXF or Axis..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, it doesn't provide a mechanism to generate the client side bindings the way Axis or CXF do. However, since it promotes Message based webservices, it will be fairly easy to manually create an adapter around Spring [WebserviceTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceTemplate.html).

And to create the types from the wsdl, java already ships with the [xjc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/xjc.html) tool which can now take in a wsdl(or schema) and generate the JAXB2 compliant java classes.